# Select radio buttons based on json response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Can I get some ideas or an example of how I could populate the checked state of radio buttons depening on data loaded from the database?

For example I am generating an array from a `SELECT` query that looks like:

```
array(
[0] => array(    
    ['note_id'] => 1
    ['value'] => 'no'
  )
[1] => array(
    ['note_id'] => 4
    ['value'] => 'yes'
  )
[2] => array(   
    ['note_id'] => 5
    ['value'] => 'yes'
  )
)
```

The checkbox groups look like :

```
<input type="radio" name="1" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="1" value="no"> 
<input type="radio" name="1" value="done">

<input type="radio" name="2" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="2" value="no"> 
<input type="radio" name="2" value="done">
```

Now using `json_encode` I put the data array of results into :

```
[{"note_id":"1","value":"no"},{"note_id":"4","value":"yes"},{"note_id":"5","value":"yes"}]
```

I am passing these results back through ajax.. something like ? :

```
$j.ajax({
    url: readurl,
    type: "GET",
    data: 'sku=' + thisSku,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data){
        // ? now what
    }       
});
```

Can someone help me understand how I now could take the json data to select the appropriate choices?  How would I create the loop that runs the check if `note_id` matches the input `[name]` attribute and if so check the button with the appropriate value?  Is json even the best way to handle this?  Should I be using `.getJSON()`?

Comment: +1 for Showing us the intention to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the success callback you can simply iterate over `data` which should be `[{"note_id":"1","value":"no"},{"note_id":"4","value":"yes"},{"note_id":"5","value":"yes"}]`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/7hp64/1/)

```
$.each (data, function (i, obj) {
    $(':radio[name=' + obj.note_id + '][value=' + obj.value + ']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {"nodes": [{"note_id":"1","value":"no"},{"note_id":"4","value":"yes"},{"note_id":"5","value":"yes"}] }

$('input:radio').attr('checked','')
$.each(data.nodes,function(a,b){
  $("input[name="+b.note_id+"][value="+b.value+"]:radio").attr('checked','checked')

} )
```

Maybe something like that would work for you...

Answer (score 2):

Create a $.each() loop on the json object and then compare the note_id with the name value and add a property

```
var notas = [{"note_id":"1","value":"no"},{"note_id":"4","value":"yes"},{"note_id":"5","value":"yes"}];


$.each(notas,function(i, v){
    $('input[type=radio][name=' + this.note_id + ']').prop('checked','true');

});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/wLDHk/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$j.ajax({
    url: readurl,
    type: "GET",
    data: 'sku=' + thisSku,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data){
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            alert("note_id: " + item.note_id + ", value: " + item.value);
        });
    }       
});
```

You hace to replace de alerts with your code.

Greatings.